# How to interprete a 1 dimensional CNN

Tags: interpretation, conv-neural-network

There is quite a bit of info to find about interpreting CNNs using 2 dimensional convolution layers. But not much about CNNs using one dimensional layers. How can one go about finding out which features are important for 1 dimensional CNNs.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/344498